# Query results is not right

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, join

I want to retrieve total bills and payments fro each suppliers to show them in a report like this one:

[image]

and my database table relations is:

[image]

The results that I got from my query is very large compare with correct results !
This is my query:

```
Dim strSQL As String

strSQL = "SELECT c.sup_Name, c.sup_Place, SUM(a.bill_Total), SUM(d.pa_Value), c.sup_Id " & _
         "FROM (suppliers c LEFT JOIN bills a on c.sup_Id = a.bill_From) LEFT JOIN payments d ON c.sup_Id = d.pa_To " & _
         "WHERE (c.sup_Name LIKE '%" + txbSearch.Text + "%' OR c.sup_Place LIKE '%" + txbSearch.Text + "%') AND " & _
         "(a.bill_Date >= #" + txbFrom.Text + "# AND a.bill_Date <= #" + txbTo.Text + "#) AND " & _
         "(d.pa_EntryDate >= #" + txbFrom.Text + "# AND d.pa_EntryDate <= #" + txbTo.Text + "#)  " & _
         "GROUP BY c.sup_Id,c.sup_Name,c.sup_Place " & _
         "ORDER BY c.sup_Name asc"

OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, objConn);

OleDbDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Another thing I noted:
if there is more than one line in payments table for a specific supplier, the results will be not correct, but if there is just one payment the result with be correct ..
and the same for bills table.

Comment: what are the correct results? what results do you get from your query? when you get the correct results, what method do you use?

Comment: each supplier with total amount of payments and bills.

Comment: I would expect c.sup_Id to be unique, so grouping by c.sup_Name & c_sup_Place is superfluous

Comment: no group by needed, you need the supplier to repeat as your using a grid, just fix your order by clause, and i would do inner joins as you dont want blank bills and payments, you can add distinct if you have a 1 to many issue

Comment: I also see that you are using the same search string (txbSearch) in name AND place is this causing more matches than you want as it is ORed.

Comment: @PaulF, you have to add all columns, not just one...try it

Comment: Your grid does not match the columns in the query either.

Comment: @MichaelRudnerEvanchik , without group by an error appear (Aggregation function)

Comment: @Paulf, there is a hidden column in listview

Comment: :-) about hidden column. I have just perform a similar query on some of my tables & I only need to group on the primary key, grouping on other columns from the matching row has no effect.

Comment: @PaulF, "you tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'sup_Name' as part of an aggregation function" .. is it ok now ?

Comment: @Belal_G : With my query, all I needed to group on was the equivalent of the sup_Id field which is unique, so grouping on the equivalent of sup_Name had no effect as the pair will always be identical. If sup_Name is not unique & you grouped on that first, then grouping on sup_Id second would have an effect.

Comment: I know this rule, but the an error will appear in V.Studio ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80692/discussion-between-paulf-and-belal-g).

Comment: so keep the group by, just make everything an inner join and order correctly more fields in your order by.

Comment: same problem, nothing change